# Unable retrieving data from server side using custom columns DataTable Plugin

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatable

i am trying to retrieving data by custom searching. my code work properly, but when i try to filter some data from the input box. the process, get stuck. Please can anyone tell me what I m   forgotting ?

My JQuery

```
 //this work fine retrieving data by only if i search using "Search box"
 var dataTableInstance = $("#dataTable").DataTable({
            bServerSide: true,
            sAjaxSource: 'AccountingMovementsService.asmx/GetAccountingMovements',
            "processing": true,
            sServerMethod: 'POST',
            columns: [
                {
                    'data': 'Payment'
                },
                {
                    'data': 'Account',
                },
                {
                    'data': 'customer',
                }
            ]
        });


//here I make all input box under footer columns (work fine)
$('#dataTable tfoot th').each(function () {
            var title = $(this).text();

            $(this).html("<input type='text' placeholder='" + title + "' />");

        });


  //And here i get stuck processing ... and data not come
  dataTableInstance.columns().every(function() {
                    var dataTableColumn = this;
                    $(this.footer()).find('input').on('keyup change', function () {
                        dataTableColumn.search(this.value).draw();
                    });
                });
```

If i use NOT SERVER-SIDE all work fine

My c# code is

```
 [WebMethod]
    public void GetAccountingMovements(int iDisplayLength, int iDisplayStart, int iSortCol_0, string sSortDir_0, string sSearch)
    {

        int displayLength = iDisplayLength;
        int displayStart = iDisplayStart;
        int sortCol = iSortCol_0;
        string sortDir = sSortDir_0;
        string search = sSearch;
        int filteredCount = 0;
        var accountingTransactions = new List<AccountMovement>();
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sg4DevMaster"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAccountingTransactions", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "DisplayLength",
                Value = displayLength
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "DisplayStart",
                Value = displayStart
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "SortCol",
                Value = sortCol
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "SortDir",
                Value = sortDir
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "Search",
                Value = search
            });

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                AccountMovement am = new AccountMovement();

                filteredCount = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["totalCount"]);
                am.payment = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["payment"]);
                am.Account = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["account"]);
                am.Customer = rdr["Customer"].ToString();

                accountingTransactions.Add(am);

            }

        }

        var result = new
        {
            iTotalRecords = GetAccountingMovementsTotalCount(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredCount,
            aaData = accountingTransactions
        };

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(result));

    }
```

All work fine using "the main search input box" in the DataTable Plugin, but it get stuck when put some data in one of custom input box placed in the footer

Thank for you time!

Comment: to start with, you are using legacy DataTable syntax what will not work with version 1.10 +.

Comment: Also, you are going to trigger multiple trips to the server but you have not implemented the "draw" parameter so DataTable has now way of keeping them in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to my GitHub https://github.com/bindrid/DataTablesServerSide take a look at the c# classes. That is how I take the parameters provided by DataTable and turn it into a usable c# object.

Also listed there is my web method that uses those classes.

Below is the DataTables logic, including your search stuff and it all works.

```
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "rowCallback": function (row, data) {
                if ($.inArray(data.employeeId, selected) !== -1) {
                    table.row(row).select();
                }
            },
            "infoCallback": function (settings, start, end, max, total, pre) {
                  var api = this.api();
                var pageInfo = api.page.info();
                return 'Page '+ (pageInfo.page+1) +' of '+ pageInfo.pages + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            },
            rowId:"employeeId",
            "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {},
            "columns":  [
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "position" },
                { "data": "office" },
                { "data": "extn" },
                { "data": "start_date" },
                { "data": "salary" }
            ],
            "select":"multi",
            "lengthMenu": [5, [10, 15, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 15, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "pageLength": 5,
            "ajax": {
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "wsSample.asmx/GetDTDataUnserializedObject",
                type: "Post",
                data: function (dtParms) {
                    // notice dtParameters exactly matches the web service

                    return JSON.stringify({ dtParameters: dtParms });
                },
                // Data filter is a part of ajax and lets you look at the raw
                dataFilter: function (res) {
                    // You probably know by know that WebServices
                    // puts your data in an object call d. these two lines puts it
                    // in the form that DataTable expects
                    var parsed = JSON.parse(res);

                    return  JSON.stringify(parsed.d);
                },
                error: function (x, y) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log(x);
                }
            },
            order: [[0, 'asc']]
        });

        // add search boxes to footer
        $('#example tfoot th').each(function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html("<input type='search' placeholder='" + title + "' />");
        });
        //And here i get stuck processing ... and data not come
        table.columns().every(function () {
            var dataTableColumn = this;
            $(this.footer()).find('input').on('keyup change', function () {
                dataTableColumn.search(this.value).draw();
            });
        });
```

Comment: thank you. Bindrid. i will take a look your github page. and post my results